# Secondary nodes in mysql 8.0.15 innodb cluster are not reading group_replication_member_expel_timeout variable from my.cnf

Tags: mysql-8.0, mysql-innodb-cluster

I have setup a 3 node mysql 8.0.15 innodb cluster. I have been trying to set `group_replication_member_expel_timeout` variable to `60` via the `/etc/my.cnf` file. Although the primary node has read the variable properly, secondary nodes are not picking up this variable and are still using the default value `0`.

Here are the contents of the `/etc/my.cnf` file

```
[mysqld]
default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password

datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
group_replication_member_expel_timeout=60
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
character-set-server = utf8
```

After restart, here are the variables in the mysqld instance.

```
mysql> select @@version;
+-----------+
| @@version |
+-----------+
| 8.0.15    |
+-----------+

mysql> select @@group_replication_member_expel_timeout;
+------------------------------------------+
| @@group_replication_member_expel_timeout |
+------------------------------------------+
|                                        0 |
+------------------------------------------+
```

I've tried replacing `group_replication_member_expel_timeout` with `group-replication-member-expel-timeout` in the `/etc/my.cnf`, with no success. 
I've also noticed that all other variables are being read properly, it is only a problem with `group_replication_member_expel_timeout` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the MySQL Shell and the AdminAPI to set up and manage MySQL InnoDB clusters there's no need, and it's **not recommended**, to manually change MySQL Server system variables and other configurations. The AdminAPI provides the functionalities to do any required configuration changes.

Regarding your need to change the value of *group_replication_member_expel_timeout*, what you need to do is as simple as:

```
cluster.setOption("expelTimeout", 60)
```

This command ensures the option is set on all the cluster members.

To verify the options being used by your cluster, you can use the following function:

```
cluster.options()
```

For more information please consult the InnoDB cluster userguide:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-innodb-cluster-working-with-cluster.html#mysql-innodb-cluster-setting-options

And for some examples and further details you can check the blog posts series published during the 8.0.14 release:

https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-innodb-cluster-whats-new-in-the-8-0-14-ga-release/

The series includes posts explaining the usage of the ['expelTimeout' option](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-innodb-cluster-controlling-data-consistency-and-expel-timeouts/) and also how to [change cluster options 'live'](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-innodb-cluster-changing-cluster-options-live/).

Cheers,

Miguel